# How to update repository after branch pull

Tags: mercurial

When I create a new branch with Mercurial, I'm able to pull only that certain branch with :

```
hg pull -b <branchname>
```

The console prints the number of the files that had been modified, so not a problem with this.

But when I do :

```
hg update
```

The repository is not updated and so I have to merge this new branch and return to "default" branch in order to have these updates.

please what is the problem here?

Comment: you need to commit your changes

Answer (score 0):

When you pull specific branch, you (by design) pull branch's HEAD and all it's ancestors

Mergeset, which merge this head into default branch (*if exist*) is not

- ancestor of branch-head
- changeset in branch `<branchname>`

and due to these two reasons can not be pulled.

It's not a problem, but correct and expected behavior.

If you asked "Why I didn't update to  head", you have to re-read `hg help update`

> If no changeset is specified, update to the **tip of the current named branch**

(i.e if your `.` was in default branch before, `hg up` will not change branch, you must `hg up <branchname>` for cross-branch updating)